# Wolf school glitch?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have a major problem. I downloaded the dlc for the wolf school witcher gear. Then i proceeded to find all of the upgrades for every element of the gear. But the problem is that i literally cant find the base weapons and armor. I looked up walkthroughs for the gear and went to the locations to get them ie. The skeletons in kaer morhen and they do not glow red for me to loot them. Has anyone else experience this?? If so please tell me how to fix this if u figured it out. I hope i dont have to back track to an older save.

Comment: Are you playing on PC or console? Are you absolutely positive that you didn't loot the gear and then sell them away? Positive that you can't craft them already? The game gives you no indication what you have found before. Are your quest logs gone for the witcher wolf school gear?

Answer (score -3):

```
BEAR URSINE SCHOOL

additem('Bear School Crossbow schematic')
additem('Bear School silver sword schematic')
additem('Bear School steel sword schematic')
additem('Bear Pants schematic')
additem('Bear Gloves schematic')
additem('Bear Boots schematic')
additem('Bear Armor schematic')
```

Remove the word "schematic" from the above to obtain the desired item, not the diagram.